# Inverse Laplace transform with sympy takes long time

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to execute the code below

```
from sympy import *
t, s, k, tauz, tau, dzeta = symbols('t s k tauz tau dzeta')

F = k * ((tauz*s + 1)/(tau**2*s**2 + 2*tau*dzeta*s + 1))
IL = inverse_laplace_transform(F, s, t)
```

the problem is that it takes so long to compute this. Actually, I don't know how long as I didn't wait until the end because it should be fast (in Matlab it is done in a flash). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you need to work with complex numbers? If you provide parameter `real=True` to symbols, it will pass in a few seconds. Like this: `t, s, k, tauz, tau, dzeta = symbols('t s k tauz tau dzeta', real=True)`

Comment: @druskacik Thank you so much! It works as it should now.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Comment: @druskacik hey can you help me with this transfer function `K*(s + 1/T)/(s*(s**2 + s*(K + 3) + 1/T)` . I have set all symbols to real but still it is taking a lot of time to compute.

Answer (score 0):

To help `sympy` compute the inverse Laplace transform, we can try to expand into  partial fractions first:

```
from sympy import *
# t, s, k, tauz, tau, dzeta = symbols('t s k tauz tau dzeta')
# using smaller names for the variables, renaming for better readability
t, s, k, z, τ, ζ = symbols('t s k z τ ζ')

F = k * ((z*s + 1)/(τ**2*s**2 + 2*τ*ζ*s + 1))
F1 = apart(F, s, full=True).doit()  # compute partial fractions
F1
```

[image]

The denominators only now contain expression involving `s`. We can use the inverse Laplace transform table and the linearity property to immediately obtain the desired result.

[image]

Let's do it with `sympy`, but let's use substitution to make the expressions cleaner. Also, we shall assume the substitution variables to be *real*.

```
Z = symbols('Z', real=True)
F1 = F1.subs(sqrt((ζ-1)*(ζ+1)), Z)
a, b = symbols('a b', real=True)
F1 = F1.subs((-Z+ζ)/τ, -a)
F1 = F1.subs((Z+ζ)/τ, -b)
F1 # after substitution
```

[image]

Now, use the inverse Laplace transform function:

```
inverse_laplace_transform(F1, s, t)
```

[image]

We can substitute `Z`, `a`, `b` back to get the final output, which will be quite messy.